# Is "I put it in quotes" idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I feel that it sounds weird although it should be ok.

Is "I put it inside quotes" better? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, in the dialects I'm familiar with, ***in*** is more natural and idiomatic than *inside*.

Now, the *why* is a gut feeling rather than anything I know about from theory. There's a natural tendency for any expression that is used frequently to be shorter (*that* is confirmed in theory). People prefer things to be shorter if possible. Both *in* and *inside* make sense here, but *in* is shorter, but to write and to say, and therefore preferable.

*Inside* is more likely to be used in cases where there's an emphasis, or a contrast with *outside*.

> This one is *inside* the quotes, while that one is *outside*.